# Getting the image URL from a field_image on a node

Tags: 8, media

So I have this Node:

```
object(Drupal\node\Entity\Node)[1862]
  protected 'values' => 
    array (size=17)
      'vid' => 
        array (size=1)
          'x-default' => string '7' (length=1)
      'langcode' => 
        array (size=1)
          'x-default' => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => 
                array (size=1)
                  'value' => string 'en' (length=2)
      ... (more fields)
      'field_image' => 
        array (size=1)
          'x-default' => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => 
                array (size=5)
                  'target_id' => string '1' (length=1)
                  'alt' => string '' (length=0)
                  'title' => string '' (length=0)
                  'width' => string '150' (length=3)
                  'height' => string '120' (length=3)
```

Now the field_image has an array with x-default and some basic image data. How do I show the image, or create a link to the image inside the Twig template?

Comment: Don't have time to check but maybe as simple as `url(node.field_image.0.entity.uri)` ([relevant issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2073811))

Comment: @Clive I tried this and gives me this error: `Recoverable fatal error: Object of class Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemList could not be converted to string`

so I tried it with this:

`url(node.field_image.0.entity.uri.value)`but then it just tells me this: `Twig_Error_Runtime: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Route "public://image.png" does not exist.")`

Comment: Errr...I would guess it needs to be done in a preprocess hook then, unless there's a Twig helper function to convert `FieldItemList`s into a string representation (which I can't find)

Comment: Oh I see, `url()` wants a route. How about `url_from_path(node.field_image.0.entity.uri.value)`?

Comment: Hmm `url_from_path()` seems to generate this: `http://mywebsite.local/public%3A//image.png` so it seems to be urlencoding and appending the exact value to the url

Comment: Out of ideas off the top of my head I'm afraid, will try to have a look later on today

Comment: Seems like I will need `file_create_url()` [see](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21file.inc/function/file_create_url/8) but there's no Twig function for it :/

Comment: There [will be](https://www.drupal.org/node/2308187) :)

Comment: Ah! Thanks :) I'll just patch it until it's in core then

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Here is an update version of for this answer after 8.0.x. This base on [@joelpittet](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/3998/joelpittet) comment.

```
{{ file_url(node.field_image.entity.fileuri) }}
```

Comment: Please note, that you will get the url of the "unstyled" original image and not the image style specific url (e.g. thumbnail). Aside from VladimirM's answer there is no way to get the correct styled image url in twig. At least currently...

Comment: ... image styles are now available in Twig Tweak - https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak

Comment: The File class has a `url()` method, so you can simply call `entity.url()` rather than passing `entity.fileuri` to `file_url()`

Comment: I don't believe that is allowed - when I tried calling `url()` i got a twig error: `Calling url method on a Drupal\file\Entity\File object is not allowed.` Drupal docs say to use the `file_url()` method too: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/functions-in-twig-templates#s--file-urluri

Comment: You should use the *file_url_generator* service in a hook or maybe a custom field formatter. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2940031. `file_create_url()`  and other methods are now deprecated. IMHO you shouldn't be using template files. Just use simple variables and avoid to drill down like this.

Answer (score 51):

I don't know about Twig, but you get the file URI with `$node->field_image->entity->getFileUri()` in PHP, and the you need to call `file_create_url()` on that:

```
file_create_url($node->field_image->entity->getFileUri())
```

I don't know if that is possible in twig. If it's not possible, you can always calculate it in preprocess and add as a new variable.

Comment: We are trying to get file_create_url() into core but lack of interest has made the issue stale.  https://www.drupal.org/node/2168231
Though if that got in it should be {{ file_url(node.field_image.entity.fileuri) }}

Answer (score 33):

If someone needed a styled image:

```
$styled_image_url = ImageStyle::load('large')->buildUrl($node->field_image->entity->getFileUri());
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Note that in your *.theme* or *.module* file you'll want to add this to the top: `use Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle;`

Comment: I ran into an issue with https, where Safari won't show the image as it uses the IP instead. You may want to add `$relative = file_url_transform_relative($styled_image_url);` to ensure it's relative. [API here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21file.inc/function/file_url_transform_relative/8.2.x)

Answer (score 16):

None of the above twig solutions worked for me (perhaps those worked for older 8.x versions but not for 8.5 version

```
{{ file_url(node.field_image['#items'].entity.uri.value) }}
```

NOTE: should be working for Drupal **8.5+**

Comment: I think its bad that these kind of things get deprecated after a while. Upgrading Drupal should keep those working! This works for me in Drupal 8.6, thanks.

Comment: {{ file_url(node.field_image['#items'].entity.uri.value) }}

Worked fine for me in my 8.8.2 version. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

This is the way if you want to get the image URL with the associated image style for any image field in a twig template:

First install the [Twig Tweak module](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak)

Then set the image URI as a variable.
With the URI, you can use a twig tweaks pattern to get the path with whatever image style you want. See below:

```
{% set image_uri = content.field_feature_row_image['#items'].entity.uri.value %}

<img src="{{ image_uri|image_style('image1200x1103') }}"/>
```

Twig Tweak v2.4+ offers `file_url` filter to extract file URL from an entity.

```
<img src="{{ node.field_image|file_url }}"/>
```

And as of Twig Tweak v2.6 you can use `file_uri` filter in conjunction with `image_style`.

```
<img src="{{ node.field_image|file_uri|image_style('image1200x1103') }}"/>
```

Answer (score 9):

What ended up working for me in D8 is:

```
$imageUrl = $node->get('field_image')->entity->uri->value;
```

Using `kint($node->get('field_image')->entity)` and looking through the array was very helpful

[image]

Then in my twig file I used:

```
<img class="top-article-image" src="{{ file_url(imageUrl) }}" />
```

Comment: what if there is not image inserted and we have set default value.

Answer (score 7):

So I've found out the answer with the help of [Clive](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/2800/clive).

Getting the image URI in a template file is done using
`node.field_image.0.entity.uri.value`. [Provide a Twig extension for `file_create_url()`](https://www.drupal.org/node/2308187), closed as fixed on January, 2015, made possible to use `file_url()` in a template file.

```
{{ file_url(node.field_image.0.entity.uri.value) }}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm always using a helper function

```
  /**
   * Get the Image URI.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity $entity
   * @param $fieldName
   * @param bool $imageStyle
   * @return mixed
   */
  public function getImageUri(\Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity $entity, $fieldName, $imageStyle = FALSE) {
    $imageField = $entity->get($fieldName)->getValue();
    if (!empty($imageField[0]['target_id'])) {
      $file = File::load($imageField[0]['target_id']);
      if ($imageStyle) {
        return ImageStyle::load($imageStyle)->buildUrl($file->getFileUri());
      }

      // Original URI.
      return file_create_url($file->getFileUri());
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can get the url directly by using field_image.entity.url

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend using the [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) module to get the URL from an image field in your twig template. Once you have installed the module you can then use various methods for extracting the URL from the image field. The following worked for me:

```
{{ node.field_main_image.0 | file_url }}
```

I set the background image of a `<div>` with the following:

```
<div style="background-image: url({{ node.field_banner_image.0 | file_url }})">
...
</div>
```

**Make sure to add style for width and height or you won't see if it's working**

**IF THIS DOES NOT WORK FOR YOU**, or if you want to learn all about the other great things twig tweak can do, reference this [cheat sheet](https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/twig-tweak/cheat-sheet#s-file-url-filter). This helpful document will save you a ton of time. I wish I knew about it earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Gosh, it actually took my ages to find out why my resulting URLs didn't work. The all 404'ed. **You need to create a derivate first if it doesn't already exist**.

So for example when you add an image style later, after the original image was uploaded, then there's no styled image file yet (the image derivate). It needs to be created first.

Replace `field_MYIMAGE` and `MYSTYLE` as you need.

```
$original_image = $node->field_MYIMAGE->entity->getFileUri();
$style = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('image_style')->load('MYSTYLE');

$destination = $style->buildUri($original_image);
if (!file_exists($destination)) {
  $style->createDerivative($original_image, $destination);
}

$url = $style->buildUrl($original_image);
```

---

I wish this would happen automatically.

Answer (score 1):

To Get image attribute like URI, alt, title etc use the syntax like below template wise

In node twig template

```
{{node.field_name.entity.fileuri}}
```

In field twig template

```
{{content.field_name.entity.fileuri}}
```

In other field twig template

```
{{element['#object'].field_name.entity.fileuri}}
```

**Note:** Also check [twig_tweaks](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) module [cheat sheet](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/twig-tweak/cheat-sheet-8x-2x) for detail related to twig related issue.

Answer (score 1):

This adds a drupal image style and the image alt test

```
{{ file_url(content.field_featured_image|field_target_entity.field_media_image.entity.uri.value| image_style('featured_image')) }}" alt="{{ content.field_featured_image|field_target_entity.field_media_image.alt }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll probably thank me in the future:

```
content.field_name['#items'][0]|file_uri|image_style('style_name')
```

(with [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak))

Answer (score 0):

somewhat related, here is what I used (thanks to all previous answers to get me there) to get an image file URL from a media entity's image field in twig:

```
{% set media_img_url = file_url(content.field_media_image.0['#item'].entity.uri.value) %}
```

now I can use this variable in my twig template

```
{{ media_img_url }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `url()` method that is on the File class as a shortcut so:

```
{{ file_url(node.field_image.entity.fileuri) }}
```

can be shortened to:

```
{{ node.field_image.entity.url }}
```

This works in preprocess functions but triggers a `Twig_Sandbox_SecurityError` when called in a twig template.

If you receive `Twig_Sandbox_SecurityError` you can tell twig to allow `url` in your settings.php file as mentioned in this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45323981/2072075)

See documentation on File::Url() https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21src%21Entity%21File.php/function/File%3A%3Aurl/8.6.x

Answer (score 0):

Just noting: use file_uri, not file_url.

```
{{ node.field_image|file_uri|image_style('content_header') }}
```