# How to get author_picture URL from a template?

Tags: 8, theming

How to get **author_picture** URL from a template ? I know that I can use `{{ author_picture }`} to display the picture; however, all I need is the URL and not the picture. I'm trying to get this URL from the template **node--article.html.twig**

Here is a similar question but this is different because is base on the field_image. [Getting the image URL from a field_image on a node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/137319/getting-the-image-url-from-a-field-image-on-a-node/184636#184636) and all I'm trying to get is the author picture.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: I have not try it out yet, because I do not want to have a module dependency for a contrib theme that I'm building.

I found another workaround ( a theory ) which is trying to get the URL from template field "author_picture" and then call that template inside of the node--article.html.twig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [URL FORMATTER](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter) module

> This module add a url formatter for image field. Then you can output image url directly.

Once enabled, go to your user manage fields, and change the picture field formatter to url.

```
{{ author_picture }}  // will display url instead of picture
```

If you are using views, views will give you an option to change the format to url.

Comment: I guess there is not other way without using that module. =(