# Can i specify an image style in my custom module

Tags: theming, 8, media

I search everywhere in the web but i dont find any solution.

I make an entity query for get some nodes. I pass the nodes to my template. In there nodes, i have an image field. So my questions is, can i specify an image style in this case ?

*Controllers.php*

```
$query = $this->entity_query->get('node');
$query->condition('type', 'foo');
$nids = $query->execute();
$foos = $this->entity_manager->getStorage('node')->loadMultiple($nids);
return array(
        '#theme' => 'foo',
        '#foos' => $foos
    );
```

template.html.twig

```
{% for foo in foos %}
    <img src='{{ file_url(foo.field_picture.entity.uri.value) }}'>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several options:

1. Use a view
2. Use [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) with a display mode, where you configure the image style
3. Use this code [How to find image style URL from within twig template?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/194749/how-to-find-image-style-url-from-within-twig-template)

If you don't need more than what is in your question, I would start with 1, because don't reinvent code for things that are in core.