# How to interpret kint output

Tags: theming, 8, entities

I have installed devel kint module on my drupal 8. Everything is fine with the module.

But my problem is how should I interpret the output of kint correctly. Especially when I want to render field within file entity.

**Here is the scenario:**

1. I have a form created with YAMLForm in my front. In that form user can upload image.
2. User submit the form.
3. When I debug data with kint, I can see the url of the image, but I am
   unnable to display it thru .

Please find below a screenshot of the kint output

[image: kint output]

**I have tryied with the following but no chance :**

```
{{ file_url(data.picture['#value']['#file'].entity['#values'].uri['x-default']) }}
{{ file_url(data.picture.0['#item'].entity.uri.value) }}
{{ file_url(data.picture.entity.fileuri) }}
```

I've Googled for hours but couldn't find any clues.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: see [Get Image URL in Twig](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185052/get-image-url-in-twig)

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the [image url formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter) and when you `{{ content.field_name[0] }}` it will print the url instead of the actual picture as long as you set the field formatter to `url formatter`

Answer (score 2):

You can't load protected values. So kint is not much help here.

But you can try this, load directly the uri value:

```
{{ file_url(data.picture['#value']['#file'].uri.value) }}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tryied it out and it works like a charm