# How to find Image URI in Kint via .entity in the node tree

Tags: theming, media, uri

I am working on Drupal 8 finally and using the replacement for Krumo which is Kint. It packs a lot more information in than Krumo did, and came with a bit of confusion.

While trying to get the image uri of an image that was rendered via a content type, the uri was not listed. I did however find an answer here [Get Image URL in Twig](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185052/get-image-url-in-twig#answer-185085) .

And I saw that my reference needed `.entity.uri.value` prepended to it. This worked, but after further inspection of my node tree in kint I could not find anything the led to .entity as a reference. So how do I found out what to appended to my node tree reference if it is not listed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every image in Drupal 8 is a file entity.

You can try in [`template_preprocess_node()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/8.2.x):

```
$image_file_id = $variables['node']->field_image[0]->target_id;
$image_file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($image_file_id);
$uri = $image_file->uri->value;
```

Comment: It seems there is just an image file id in kint without uri info