# How can I preprocess a node field value to make it accessible in the template level beneath field level (video template inside file field)

Tags: 8, theming

I am using the [Video.js (HTML5 Video Player)](https://www.drupal.org/project/videojs) module and I would like to add an image for the poster by loading the URL of another image field in the same node (without modifying the module itself).

How can I preprocess that URL to get it inside the module template?

I tried to get the URL variable as {{ poster }} into the template file videojs.html.twig, by adding following preprocess function in the theme-file:

`function templatename_preprocess_videojs(&$variables, $hook) {
  if ($variables['element']['#field_name'] == 'field_image_poster') {
      $variables['poster'] = $variables['element']['#object']->getURL();
  }
}`

PS: Thank you for the suggested solution. This would work if I would have expressed myself correctly. But it's not the field level were I do not get the variable, its one level deeper (the video template beneath the file field level).

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! This is a rather broad question as it is asking what code to use without showing any code. The code is at least necessary to avoid a reply like _I already tried that code and it doesn't work_ given to an answer showing the code to use. If you still have to write code to achieve what you described, you are asking the question too early.

Comment: I totally understand your review. I am a little bit wooried about my lack of understanding of preprocess functions in general. Nevertheless I added the code I tried to achieve my goal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Image URL in Twig](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185052/get-image-url-in-twig) - `element[#object]` is the parent node, not the image field.

Comment: Thank you for the suggested solution that would work if I would have expressed myself correctly. But it's not the field level were I do not get the variable, its one level deeper (the video template beneath the file field).