# Get the URL to use it in an <a> tag in a file field

Tags: files, paragraphs

I'm looking to print out the url for a file in a Drupal File field in the twig template. I'm doing this inside a paragraph twig file.

I've followed a similar answers on stack overflow but to no joy.

The field is a File field with no other specific configuration.

```
<a href="{{ file_url(content.field_file.entity.uri.value) }}" class="download-file download-row file">...</a>
```

I've tried setting the link display as *URL to File* as that's all I need, but it still wont render out the URL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Image URL in Twig](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185052/get-image-url-in-twig)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite follow. I'm looking for a file (doc, pdf etc) not an image. And I'm doing this at paragraph twig level so I'd be using content.field_name. I've tried setting the link display as 'URL to File' as thats all I need, but it still wont render out the url.

Comment: There is no difference between images and files. And use the data object `node.field_myfile...` (or `paragraph.field_myfile...` if inside paragraph template) as source, not the render array `content.field_myfile...`