# How can I get the url from an user selected image?

Tags: theming, 8

**Version: Drupal 8**

I want to make the header region of my drupal customizable. The region consists of a title and a background image. I want the user to upload an image or select an image. That has to be echoed into the background: url("test.jpg");.

```
<div style="background: url(Image url)">
```

This should be available on every page except the homepage. I have tried some solutions for older versions of drupal but I couldn't find one for drupal 8.

Comment: If you already done it in older version, you could tell the steps how did you do, so we can help you in D8 where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just fixed it by using:

```
{{ file_url(node.field_‌​image.entity.fileuri) }}
```

in combination with imce. IMCE had an option of selecting from the server as an extra option on top of the uploading functionality.The function

```
 node.field_image.ent‌​ity.fileuri
```

got the url of the field: field_image. This is where I found it: [link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/137319/getting-the-image-url-from-a-field-image-on-a-node?rq=1)