# Get url from image field in paragraphs

Tags: 8, media, paragraphs

I have a node with a field called "field_paragraph" which is a paragraph reference.
Referencing a paragraph type which has a field called "field_image"

I'm trying to get the url of the field_image in a custom module and so far i have this. But i don't seem to get it work.

```
use Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph; 
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
$node = Node::load($nid);
$paragraph_field = $node->get("field_paragraph")->getValue();
$paragraph = Paragraph::load($paragraph_field[0]['target_id']);
```

Here is where the problem occurs

```
$uri = $paragraph->field_image->entity->getFileUri();
```

The above returns nothing.

I used kint to print "$paragraph->field_image->entity" and it returns null. 
What I'm I doing wrong? I tried all answers I could find on here to no avail.

After getting the uri I think calling the below line would be enough.

```
$url = file_create_url($uri);
```

**Question:** How do I get the url of an image field in paragraphs programmatically?

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong with the code. The first step is very verbose and the second a much shorter version. But both steps are basically the same, both are reference fields, to a paragraph and a file. So you can use in the second step the verbose version you used in the first step and debug the array if there is content in the image field, that means a `target_id` to the image file.

Comment: Linking https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/224294/how-to-get-an-image-url-from-a-field-in-a-twig-template which deals with a very similar question from a PHP point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pretty much there but when calling the field name use the method get()

```
$uri = $paragraph->get('field_image')->entity->getFileUri();
```

Then once you have the uri you'll be able to get the full url

```
$url = file_create_url($uri);
```