# How do I print an image field value in views-view.html.twig?

Tags: views, theming

It seems I'm able to print text field values with `{{ view.field.field_example.getvalue(view.result[0]) }}`, but this same method doesn't work for image fields. Please help.

Comment: What value from the image field do you want to print ? Have you looked at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/224294/how-to-get-an-image-url-from-a-field-in-a-twig-template or https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/219039/rendering-an-image-field-in-page-html-twig-with-a-custom-image-style ?

Comment: I just want to render the actual image itself. The solutions you linked don't seem to work. I'm not sure if it's because those solutions are for the template page.html.twig whereas I'm using views-view.html.twig. Sorry -- I am pretty new to Twig and Drupal 8.

Comment: Sorry perhaps I did not read your question carefully.

Answer (score 0):

views-view.html.twig is not meant to be used for field printing.

You should use **views-view-fields--[view-name].html.twig**

OR

**views-view-fields--[view-name]--[[machine-name]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDJ1q.jpg).html.twig** if you want to be even more specific.

and there you just do

`{{ fields.field_name.content }}`

---

> For multi value fields, is there a way to print just one value within a field at a time?

```
{% set field_values = row._entity.get('field_name').getValue() %}
{% for field_value in field_values %}
    <li>{{ field_value['value'] }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

> By doing {{ fields.field_color_hex.content }}, I printed them all at
>   once.

In your case:

```
{% set hexes = row._entity.get('field_color_hex').getValue() %}
{% for hex in hexes %}
    <li>{{ hex['value'] }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I was using views-view-fields.html.twig before, but I found I couldn't print individual values within a field. For instance, I have a field called field_color_hex which contains multiple hex values for different colors. By doing {{ fields.field_color_hex.content }}, I printed them all at once. Is there a way to print just one value within a field at a time?

Comment: @Bri updated answer.