# How to print alt or title field image in twig node template?

Tags: theming, 8

I want to print alt or title field image file in node twig template Drupal 8. I tried use `{{ node.field_images.entity }}` to debug get value title or alt but in class `\Drupal\file\Entity\File` not function get those ! I saw `{{node.field_images.entity.fileuri}}` in [link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/137319/getting-the-image-url-from-a-field-image-on-a-node)

So how to used `{{node.field_images.entity}}` to get value alt or title file images ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The alt and title properties are stored in the image field, not in the file entity. You can access them by replacing the `entity` property with `alt` or `title`:

```
{{ node.field_image.title }}
{{ node.field_image.alt }}
```

Answer (score 10):

In the field template (field.html.twig) this will work.

```
{% for item in items %}
    {{ item.content['#item'].alt }}
{% endfor %}
```

In node.html.twig or paragraph.html.twig, this will work.

```
{{ content.field_image['#items'].alt }}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the node template:

```
{{ content.field_image[0]['#attributes']['alt'] }}
```