# How to print paragraph image title/alt in custom twig template?

Tags: theming

How to display the alt and title text in drupal twig template? I already enable the alt and title field, but don't know how to print the field.

[image]

Here is the code in custom twig template. I want to display it in the image tag.

```
<div class="s-carousel s-carousel-product">
                {% for row in data.dynamic %}
                <div>
                    <div class="prd" prd-id="{{row.id}}" prd-title="{{row.variant.product.title}}" prd-buy-now="{{row.uri}}#buynow" prd-learn-more="{{row.uri}}">
                        <div class="con-img-wrapper">
                            <div class="con-img">
                                <div class="img-bg" style="background-image:url({{row.variant.product.bg}});"></div>
                                <div class="con-img-inner">
                                    <img class="img-prd" src="{{row.variant.product.sizes.0.img}}" alt="???"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print alt or title field image in twig node template?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/231656/how-to-print-alt-or-title-field-image-in-twig-node-template)

Comment: @leymannx tried {{node.field_image['#row'].alt}} and also {{row.variant.product.sizes.field_image['#row'].alt}}, but not working