# How do I programmatically get the URL of an entity referenced media image field using on a custom_preprocess_html() hook on THEME.theme?

Tags: 8, media

**Reason:** I need to create an Open graph meta tag og:image and pass the URL as content.

On THEME_preprocess_html(), I loaded the node using

```
$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
      $nid = $node->id();
      if($node->hasField('field_image')){
        $image_id = $node->field_image->target_id;
        $image = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('file')->load($image_id);
      }
}
```

I have loaded the node and I was able to get the field_image_entity_id as shown. I want to get the URL of the image field of entity referenced field.

The below code gives me NULL. How can I load the media entity and get this value?

```
$image = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('file')->load($entity_img_id);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the image URL from a field\_image on a node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/137319/getting-the-image-url-from-a-field-image-on-a-node)

Comment: @GiorgosK I want to get the url first then I can print it. I am trying to get this in a preprocess hook and will use the twig template to render it.

Comment: I have tried the solution suggested by Berdir on that page but I am unable to load the url. $node->field_image->entity->getFileUri()

Comment: What do you mean by `its displaying the wrong file located in public directory`, your question perhaps is missing some vital information.  How are you getting the `entity_img_id` ?

Comment: Hi Giorgosk, I am getting the entity_image_id from $node->field_image->target_id; I am loading the entity using Media::load($field_image_id); this returns NULL, I used \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('file')->load($entity_img_id); and this returns the wrong file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, here is what worked for me. After digging through stack overflow, found that I was missing the ImageStyle and this resulted in not rendering the url.

I added

```
use Drupal\media\Entity\Media;
use Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle;
use Drupal\media_entity\MediaInterface;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
```

and then on preprocess function, I loaded the media using the target_id that I got form the $node->field_image->target_id;

Then, I loaded the ImageStyle using

```
$media = Media::load($image_id);
$media_url = ImageStyle::load('TYPE_OF_CROP')->buildUrl($media->image->entity->getFileUri());
$variables['media_url'] =  $media_url;
```

Hopefully this helps people.

Answer (score 2):

[`file_create_url` has been deprecated. Use `\Drupal::service('file_url_generator')` instead](https://www.drupal.org/node/2940031).

```php
$image_uri = $node->field_my_media->entity->field_media_image->entity->getFileUri();

$image_url = \Drupal::service('file_url_generator')->generateAbsoluteString($image_uri);
```

Comment: This helped me with an image field in Drupal 10. I already had `$node->field_my_media->entity` but it had no `getFileUri()`. Only going deeper `...->entity->field_media_image->entity` gave me the `entity` that I could call `getFileUri()` on. The first `entity` is `Drupal\media\Entity\Media`, the second entity is `Drupal\file\Entity\File`.

Answer (score 1):

Just tested the following code and was able to get the image URL from `field_image` of the current node.

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  //get the current node
  $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
  if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
    if($node->hasField('field_image')){
      $image_url = file_create_url($node->field_image->entity->getFileUri());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Giorgosk, Thanks for the response. I have tried this but it doesn't work. I am getting "Website is having an unexpected error" when I check logs, I don't see any errors logged. From what I notice, when the field_image tries to get to the entity($node->field_image->entity) it throws this error.

I have used all the necessary classes on the theme file, including Node, Entity, Media, EntityManager

Comment: The answer above is a working solution of what I see in your question.  Are you trying to get the image field of the current node and pass to twig for displaying ?
Please revise your question with all details about the image field and the node and fields setup and what you are trying to accomplish might help to understand better your problem.

Comment: Hi Giorgosk, I have updated the question again to best represent the issue.

Comment: Still the title of your question is very different from what you are asking in the question.  Please revise.  Is `$entity_img_id = 2581;` known ? how did you get it ?

Comment: As mentioned I got the image id from the $node->field_image->target_id. Thanks for the input

Comment: I have tried to give context as much as I can. Let me know if this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

In more recent version of Drupal 8, you can use:

```php
$image_field = $node->get('field_image');
if ($image_field->isEmpty())
  return;
$media_entity = $image_field->referencedEntities()[0];
$uri = $media_entity->get('field_media_image')->entity->uri->value;
$variables['image_url'] = file_create_url($uri);
```