# Programmatically get View Custom Image filed url

Tags: views

I have:

```
$view = Views::getView('ads');


$view->setDisplay('block_9');



$view->execute();
$view_result = $view->result;

foreach ($view_result as $data) {
  $entity = $data->_entity;
  kint($entity->get('field_image_ads')->getValue());

}
```

A screenshot of Output Kint:
[image]

But I want the image URL also.
Thanks.

Comment: What kind of field is this specifically?  Are you using Media and an entity reference or the Image field?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the image URL from a field\_image on a node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/137319/getting-the-image-url-from-a-field-image-on-a-node)

Comment: yes, now my problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `field_image_ads` looks like an entity reference field, so try this:

```
$entity->field_image_ads->entity->getFileUri();
```

Comment: Thank you, now my problem is sloved.